# Prevent GKGridGraph crashing while pathfinding

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

In my App the Pink heart want to go to the red one! But as you see the way is blocked.
The code I use is:

```
let solution = GridGraph.findPath(from: GridGraph.node(atGridPosition:int2(Int32(pinkHeart.positon.x),Int32(pinkHeart.positon.y)))!,to:GridGraph.node(a[enter image description here][1]tGridPosition:int2(Int32(redHeart.positon.x),Int32(redHeart.positon.y)))!) as! [GKGridGraphNode]
```

But the Application always crashes because there is no way!
If I want to find a path from the pink heart to the yellow/green one the code works.
I tried many different ways to solve the problem but nothing seems to work...
e.g.:

```
do {
         let solution = try GridGraph.findPath(from:GridGraph.node(atGridPosition:int2(Int32(pinkHeart.positon.x),Int32(pinkHeart.positon.y)))!, to:GridGraph.node(atGridPosition: int2(Int32(redHeart.positon.x),Int32(redHeart.positon.y)))!) as! [GKGridGraphNode]
} catch {
         print("no path found")
}
```

or

```
if let solution = GridGraph.findPath(from:GridGraph.node(atGridPosition:int2(Int32(pinkHeart.positon.x),Int32(pinkHeart.positon.y)))!, to:GridGraph.node(atGridPosition: int2(Int32(redHeart.positon.x),Int32(redHeart.positon.y)))!) as! [GKGridGraphNode] {
    //Do something!
}
```

I tried many more possible solutions, but it always crashed...
Thank you for your help!
[Thats the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g32O7.png)

Comment: This needs to get cleaned up,  it is very hard to read, and we have no idea what pink hearts and red hearts are doing because we can't see your app.

Comment: Sorry the hearts wasn't shown before... I added an image to show the case...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this Way:

```
    var solutionPath: [GKGridGraphNode]? {
        let solution = GridGraph.findPath(from: OneNode, to: anotherNode) as! [GKGridGraphNode]
        if solution.isEmpty {
            print("There is no possible path!")
            return nil
        }
        else {
            return solution
        }
    }
```